# SQLite database copy doesn't work on device itself

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a Spanish vocabulary practice application for my Nexus 7. I followed instructions necessary to (1) convert a mysql database to an SQLite database, then (2) to integrate the created SQLite database into an Android app. Building the Android app was an exercise in patience although already a very experienced programmer/database developer. To make a long story short, my database works on what appears to be a Nexus 7 emulator on my PC, but refuses to run, giving me a sqlitecantopendatabaseexception when I use adb to install the app on my Nexus 7.

I have read in some arenas that a copied SQLite database is not welcomed either on  an emulator, or on the device itself. This is obviously not the case for my emulation on Eclipse but obviously prevents running the app on the device itself. Anyone with similar experience out there?